# Pulling subsets from a large 3d matrix using a binary mask - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, partitioning

I've a large `D` Matrix of size MxNxK. Given a binary mask `B` of size MxN, I would like to split the matrix `D` into two submatrices: `D0` and `D1`, in such a way that matrix `D0` has the values of matrix `D` associated with the `0's` in the binary mask. The same is valid for `D1`, but by using the `1's` in the binary mask.
Currently, I'm solving this issue by using loops, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to solve that?

```
mat_zeros = [];
mat_ones = [];

for m=1:M
    for n=1:N

        matval = matrixbig(m,n,:);
        matval = matval(:)'; % mapping matval to a K-dimensional vector

        if (binmask(m,n) == 1)
            mat_ones   = [mat_ones; matval];
        elseif (binmask(m,n) == 0)
            mat_zeros   = [mat_zeros; matval];
        end
    end
end
```

All suggestions are welcomed ;-)

Comment: Have a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407525/how-can-i-index-a-3-d-matrix-with-a-2-d-mask-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over the `K` dimension leads to more efficient code with only one loop.  See the *Shorter algorithm* section of code below:

```
% Some data
clear; M = 3; N = 2; K = 4;
matrixbig = rand(M,N,K);
binmask = round(matrixbig(:,:,1));

% Original algorithm
mat_zeros = []; mat_ones = [];
for m=1:M
  for n=1:N
    matval = matrixbig(m,n,:);
    matval = matval(:)';

    if (binmask(m,n) == 1)
      mat_ones   = [mat_ones; matval];
    elseif (binmask(m,n) == 0)
      mat_zeros   = [mat_zeros; matval];
    end
  end
end 

% Shorter algorithm
mat_zeros1 = []; mat_ones1 = [];
mask = (binmask == 1)';
for k = 1:K
  matval = matrixbig(:,:,k)';
  mat_ones1  = [mat_ones1,  matval(mask)];
  mat_zeros1 = [mat_zeros1, matval(~mask)];
end

% Compare results of two algorithms
isequal(mat_ones,  mat_ones1 )
isequal(mat_zeros, mat_zeros1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without any loops at all, by replicating the 2d binary mask into a 3d mask the size of your data, and then doing logical indexing.

```
binmask_big = repmat(binmask, [1 1 K]);
mat_ones = matrixbig(binmask_big==1);
mat_zeros = matrixbig(binmask_big==0);
```

Comment: @ Matt, thanks, but ideally, I would like that `mat_ones` and `mat_zeros` they both have `K` columns. Following your suggestion, I get 1 column matrices.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to use linear indexing and avoid loops altogether. You must precompute the indices of ones and zeros in the mask. The following should work:

```
% You must define M,N in order for the code to work

mat_zeros = [];
mat_ones = [];

indOnes=find(binmask==1);  %returns linear indices
indZeros=find(binmask==0); %returns linear indices

mat_ones   = [matrixbig(indOnes) matrixbig(indOnes+M*N) matrixbig(indOnes+2*M*N)];
mat_zeros  = [matrixbig(indZeros) matrixbig(indZeros+M*N) matrixbig(indZeros+2*M*N)];
```

And there you have it!